# UISearchController add's offset while editing

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

UISearchController add's a offset when editing begins. In Landscape mode it works perfectly fine, but does not in portrait mode.

Are there any settings in storyboard that can help to overcome this issue.

The following works but, shows a animation which goes at +320 and then brings back to -320.

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        self.mySearchContorller.searchBar.frame=CGRectMake(-320, 0, self.myTable.frame.size.width, 44.0)

    }
```

[image]

[image]

I have used storyboard with a segue (Show Detail).Attached is a screen shot of the storyboard.

[image]

Comment: how are you presenting the UISearchController? Is it presented from the SplitViewController or from within the DetailViewController?

Comment: Its presented as DetailViewControllrt (Within UINavigationCOntroller ). From the UI, we can see it baiscally add's the offset of 320pt (the width of the master list). Don't know how to resolve this, stuck up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downloaded your project and played with it and it seems the problem is here:
Change 
`self.tblSearchController.definesPresentationContext = true` to 
`definesPresentationContext = true`

Also, you're subclassing `UITableViewController`, don't create your own table but drag one into your storyboard and use it. Here's how your `DetailViewController` should look like:
class DetailTableViewController: UITableViewController {

```
var tblSearchController:UISearchController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tblSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView=self.tblSearchController.searchBar
    definesPresentationContext = true

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let aCell:UITableViewCell! =  tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")
    return aCell
}
```

}
[image]

Comment: definesPresentationContext was the problem, If it is set to true it will cover the current controller, if the current view-controller or its descendants  presents a view controller.